# Why does const work in some for-loops in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scope, ecmascript-6, constants, let

I **do know** why `const` doesn't work in for-loops. We need to create a new scope and copy over a value into that. So this won't fly.

```
for(const i = 0; i < 5; i++) console.log(i);
```

Whereas this will.

```
for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) console.log(i);
```

However, I noticed that both of them work when looping though the properties of an object like this.

```
for(let property in thingy) console.log(property);
for(const property in thingy) console.log(property);
```

I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`for (const property in object)` works because with each iteration you get a new variable, which is scoped only to that iteration. You can easily check that by using a closure inside a loop:

```js
for (const property in {a: 1, b: 2}) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(property);
  }, 100);
}
```

This logs `a` and `b`, but if you change `const` to `var`, it logs `b` twice.

Comment: Right. But when it comes to `let` vs `const` (not `var`), there's no difference here, right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten In this case there's no difference.

Comment: but if there is no setTimeout, this work with var !! : for (var property in {a: 1, b: 2}) {console.log(property);} ; result is "a" "b" ??

Comment: @PhilippeOceangermanique because the value is logged immediately before it can change. With a `setTimeout` and a `var` it runs after the loop has finished and so each `console.log(property)` accesses *the single* variable called `property` which has the value `b` after the loop finished. With a `let` or `const` there are multiple different variables called `property` where each is in a separate scope and there is one scope per iteration.

Answer (score 21):

In your first example, `i` is modified via the `i++`. A `const` can't be modified, so you get an error.

In the second example, `property` is re-defined for each iteration (each instance falls out of scope and a new one created rather than just re-assigning to the same variable) of the `for` loop. Since you're actually re-defining rather than modifying the value, `const` works just fine.

Comment: So, basically, in **this particular** case, there's no difference between `const` and `let`, right?

Comment: @KonradViltersten - Except that `let` would allow you to modify `property` inside the `for` loop whereas `const` shouldn't.

Comment: Oh, right! So it's actually preferable here to use `const`, then. I'm **never** going to want/need to alter the value of the property's name. Cool!